# storing results outside of if/then statements

Tags: vb.net

Fist I'm really new to vb so I'm not sure if this question will make allot of sense, but I'll try to explain it the best I can

So I'm writing a program to calculate the cost of different packages for an Internet Service Provider (One of the challenges out of the book I'm learning from). The program has 3 radio buttons (to select a package) and a text box to input the number of hours. Depending on what package you select and how many hours you type in it gives an output of the price.

This is what it looks like so far:

```
Dim decMonthlyCharge As Decimal
Dim intHours As Integer
Dim decPackageA As Decimal
Dim decPackageB As Decimal
Dim decPackageC As Decimal

Try
    intHours = CInt(txtNumberofHours.Text)

    If radPackageA.Checked = True Then
        If intHours <= 10 Then
            decPackageA = CDec(9.95)
        ElseIf intHours >= 11 Then
            decPackageA = CDec(intHours - 10) * 2 + CDec(9.95)
        End If

        If chkNonProfit.Checked = True Then
            decPackageA = CDec(decPackageA - (decPackageA * 0.2))
        End If

        decMonthlyCharge = decPackageA
    End If
```

This is redone for each radio button being checked with different variables.

OK, so the reason I declared package A,B,C is that I want the program to store the values for each option and then add another checkbox that will display the savings when compared to the selected plan.
The trouble I'm having is that these calculations are only done inside the if then statements (depending on what radio button I have selected) and I want them ALL to be stored so that I can write another line of code that compares all of them...

I would really appreciate some help!

**Edit

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

    Dim decMonthlyCharge As Decimal
    Dim intHours As Integer
    Private decPackageA As Decimal
    Private decPackageB As Decimal
    Private decPackageC As Decimal



    Try
        intHours = CInt(txtNumberofHours.Text)
        If radPackageA.Checked = True Then
            If intHours <= 10 Then
                decPackageA = CDec(9.95)
            ElseIf intHours >= 11 Then
                decPackageA = CDec(intHours - 10) * 2 + CDec(9.95)
            End If
            If chkNonProfit.Checked = True Then
                decPackageA = CDec(decPackageA - (decPackageA * 0.2))
            End If
            decMonthlyCharge = decPackageA
        End If
```

I declared them as private like he said, but I don't think I did it right. What I'm saying is how can I use the results within the if then statements and use them for a calculation outside. I want the result of one package in the label that says the monthly charge, but I want to use all three variables to compare in another label that says potential savings

**edit

To give you a better idea of what I want, I wrote this at the end

```
lblMonthlyCharge.Text = decMonthlyCharge.ToString("c")

        If chkPotentialSavings.Checked = True Then

            lblPotentialSavings.Text = CStr(decPackageA - decPackageB) & " potential savings with package B"
            End If
```

**Ok, Last edit

I declared the variables outside the method and I wrote the following

'calculate savings with Package A

```
        If chkPotentialSavings.Checked = True And decMonthlyCharge = decPackageA Then
            lblPotentialSavings.Text = (decPackageA - decPackageB).ToString("C") & " potential savings with package B,  " &
                (decPackageA - decpackagec).ToString("c") & " potential savings with package C"

            'calculate savings with Package B
        ElseIf chkPotentialSavings.Checked = True And decMonthlyCharge = decPackageB Then
            lblPotentialSavings.Text = (decPackageB - decPackageA).ToString("C") & " potential savings with package A,  " &
                (decPackageB - decpackagec).ToString("c") & " potential savings with package C"

            If (decPackageB - decPackageA) <= (0) Then
                lblPotentialSavings.Text = "$0.00 potential savings with package A, " &
                    (decPackageB - decpackagec).ToString("c") & " potential savings with package C"

            End If
            'Calculate savings with Package C
        ElseIf chkPotentialSavings.Checked = True And decMonthlyCharge = decpackagec Then
            lblPotentialSavings.Text = (decpackagec - decPackageA).ToString("C") & " potential savings with package A,  " &
                (decpackagec - decPackageB).ToString("c") & " potential savings with package C "
            If (decpackagec - decPackageA) <= (0) Then
                lblPotentialSavings.Text = "$0.00 potential savings with package A,  " &
                    (decpackagec - decPackageB).ToString("c") & " potential savings with package B "
                If (decpackagec - decPackageB) <= (0) Then
                    lblPotentialSavings.Text = " $0.00 potential savings with package A,  " & " $0.00 potential savings with package B"
                End If

            End If
```

The problem is that it only stores the sales amount after I click each individual radio button and click the calculate button for each one. How would I fix this so that it would automatically do the calculations without having to click the calculate button for each individual one?

Comment: Declare *decPackageA, ...* as private (outside of radio button sub). You then can use them where ever in your class.

Comment: learn about [Scope in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx)

Comment: How do I do that "Private decPackageA As Decimal"? because that's not working

Comment: A variable only exists inside the block that it's declared in.  If you want a variable to continue to exist when a block completes then you must declare the variable outside that block.  It's that simple.  Any value you assign to the variable inside the block will then be accessible anywhere else the variable is in scope.  If you have changed your code then please edit your question and provide the current code, along with an explanation of exactly what the current behaviour is and how it differs from expectation.

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms or an ASP.NET application?

Comment: umm I'm using visual studio 2012 and its vb.net i think

Comment: That's not an answer to Gridly's question.  What type of project did you create?

Comment: You can't declare a variable `Private` or the like inside a method.  Did you read anything about scope?  You have to declare the variables OUTSIDE the method if they are going to exist once the method completes.  It's only OUTSIDE a method that `Private` is valid.

Comment: Oic its a windows forum and do you mean before the Public Class frmMain at the top of the page? I've only been doing this for like 2 weeks so thank you for the patience

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site.  every comment points you in the the same direction: study the basics of variable scope.  it may not be as fun as just banging on the keyboard, but you will learn more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is actually with the variables being used. Actually what you are using is `Local` variables, which are declared in a method and can only be used inside the method.

For a variable to be available throughout the class, that is, in different methods, you need a `Global` variable, which is declared as `Private decPackageA as decimal`. Note that declaration should be done outside the methods (at the beginning of your class, for a better visibility).

Or you can declare it as a global `Property` which will be accessible throughout the class, as below;

```
    Private _decPackageA As Decimal
    Public Property decPackageA() As Decimal
        Get
            Return _decPackageA
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            _decPackageA = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

The property is accessible as a global variable. Its main purpose is that the data can be manipulated during the `SET` or `GET`.